# Where should I register my DBAL type?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am using Doctrine's enum types to track the status of an entity that I am using in a Symfony application. I am using (roughly) the methods described here:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/cookbook/mysql-enums.html

My problem comes when I try to update the database schema. I get the following error:

```
  [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
  Unknown column type "EnumStatusType" requested. Any Doctrine type that you use has to be registered
   with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType(). You can get a list of all the known types with \Doctrin
  e\DBAL\Types\Type::getTypesMap(). If this error occurs during database introspection then you might
   have forgot to register all database types for a Doctrine Type. Use AbstractPlatform#registerDoctr
  ineTypeMapping() or have your custom types implement Type#getMappedDatabaseTypes(). If the type nam
  e is empty you might have a problem with the cache or forgot some mapping information.
```

This error is very helpful in a way -- as is the documentation -- but both of those resources leave out two pieces of information: **In which file should I use addType() to register my new type?**

Two secondary questions: Should I call the addType() method statically, as shown in the examples? If not, how should I retrieve an object in order to call the method non-statically?

Comment: With Symfony you don't need to do it manually, you can use your configuration files to register new types.. https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/dbal.html#registering-custom-mapping-types

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the symfony configuration  to add your custom types.

If you are using symfony 4+ you can into  `config/packages/doctrine.yaml` this code:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        types:
            your_custom_type:  App\Type\YourCustomType
```

If you are using symfony 3.x you can add into this file `app/config/config.yml` this code:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        types:
            your_custom_type:  AppBundle\Type\YourCustomType
```

Comment: Don't forget to clear the cache with `cache:clear` after any change :)

Comment: Does this configuration via `.yaml` use the `addType()` method under the hood to register the enum type?